# The Emberjs unable to set the model inside the promise after calling ajax call

Tags: ember.js

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`
ProjectsController = Ember.Controller.extend
  ajax:Ember.inject.service()
  actions:
    searchProject:(pid)->
      promise  = @get "ajax"
        .request "/projects/search/#{pid}"
      promise.then (data)->
        @set 'model',data
`export default ProjectsController`
```

I am calling searchProject action from the hbs file.I'm trying here to set the model inside the then function of promiss but i'm unable to do that the html in this view has to refresh with the data from the promise ajax is working fine data is returning fine i have to set this data as the model
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting error because you are using `->` you need to use `=>` (fat arrow) because you are setting property on outer context.

```
actions:
  searchProject:(pid)->
    promise  = @get "ajax"
      .request "/projects/search/#{pid}"
      .then (data)=>
        @set 'model',data
```

I might be wrong, but it looks excessive logic because you probably have same thing in your model hook in your Route so instead fetching model in `searchProject` you can transition to same route with different id (`this.transitionToRoute('my-route/' + pid`) which will give you same result

Comment: Thanks a lot i have been trying for a week on this 100 % solved the problem......... @Bek

Comment: sure ..  I should call you as Sir... @BEk